# Paths with wildcard

Tags: systemjs

I'm using SystemJs. Here is my config:

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    paths: {
        app: '/app/*',//for app look in app
        '*': '/node_modules/*' //for rest look in node_modules
    },
});
System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

With that config browser is looking for file in `node_modules/app/boot.js` - why? For `app` it should look in `/app/*`